# Regular Expression in JAVA in making a password

Tags: java, regex, passwords

I have a question. My goal is to make a password; the password must consist of two lowercase letters and 8 digits from 0-9. I have made a code for this using regular expression but the problem is that it exceeds the overall number of that the password must be which is 10 but my code here doesn't really match actually.

Here is my code:

```
System.out.print("Password: ");
        Scanner pass=new Scanner(System.in);
        String password=pass.next();
        String password_regex="(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=\\S+$).{8,}";
        boolean password_result=password.matches(password_regex);
        
        if(password_result){
```

Comment: Why do you have to do it all in one regex?  There are so many cleaner ways to do it.  Like `password.codePoints().filter(Character::isLetter).count() == 2 && password.codePoints().filter(Character::isDigit).count() == 8`.

Comment: Im really sorry that was one way that I saw that I think I can do it but failed. Im really sorry  ... Using filter will help me fix this?

Comment: No need to apologize.  I only meant to suggest that regular expressions are not the only way to check for the presence of desired characters.  My suggestion uses [a stream of the password’s characters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()), and that IntStream is what you can filter.  `count()` will then return the count of only the characters which pass the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assert 2 lowercase chars a-z between only digits, and then match 10 times either a-z or a digit.

```
^(?=\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]\d*$)[a-z\d]{10}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]\d*$)` Positive lookahead, assert 2 chars a-z between optional digits
- `[a-z\d]{10}` Repeat 10 times matching either a char a-z or a digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8DpROc/1)

In Java with double escaped backslashes

```
String regex = "^(?=\\d*[a-z]\\d*[a-z]\\d*$)[a-z\\d]{10}$";
```

Comment: I would not use a regex to solve this; I think REs are overused as a "I must solve in one expression" approach. You could maybe do half the job with a simple RE, something like `[a-z0-9]{10,}` (my syntax might be a little off) but I'd leave the "two alphabetics" for an explicit check.

Comment: @iggy Feel free to post your solution :-)

Comment: @iggy It all depends on use case. At any rate, this suggested regex is efficient, fast and safe, so there is no problem. It is very clear, too.

Comment: Hi, my aim output is that a valid password is 4ac5478959 wherein the two lowercase characters are between the digits. It starts with a digit the whatever placements of the characters as long as it is in between digits. Thank you for giving me information I can try

Comment: @user16376117 if the chars must be between digits `^(?=\d+[a-z]\d*[a-z]\d+$)[a-z\d]{10}$`   https://regex101.com/r/PzO7iG/1

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are heavyweight and are hard to read.  Highly complex ones are prone to mistakes—mistakes which the compiler cannot catch.  You might understand the regex now, but will you understand it when you come back to the code in six months?  Will other people understand it?

Unless you have a specific requirement to do the entire check with exactly one regular expression, there are better choices than regular expressions.  You can check the characters themselves:

```
boolean hasTwoLetters =
    (password.codePoints().filter(Character::isLetter).count() == 2);
boolean hasEightDigits =
    (password.codePoints().filter(Character::isDigit).count() == 8);

boolean passwordValid = hasTwoLetters && hasEightDigits;
```

Just because it looks longer than a single regex match doesn’t mean it will take longer.  Regular expression engines are complex libraries with a lot of code under the hood.  This approach just looks at the password characters one at a time and counts them.

For more information, see:

- [documentation for String.codePoints()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints())
- [documentation for IntStream.filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#filter(java.util.function.IntPredicate))